# Construct a sequence such that the associated series converges to $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to construct a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^∞ x_n =\pi$.

Is it valid to say $x_0=\pi$ and $x_n=0$ for all $n>0$ ?

Comment: It could be. It depends on the specification of the problem. Finite or infinite sequence? Any other restrictions?

Comment: Valid? Yes. But what your instructor intended? Probably not. You are probably meant to do something related to Taylor series.

Comment: No other restrictions were given.

Comment: if that was how the question was stated, then almost. Take $x_n=0$ for all $n>0$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong we haven't done Taylor series and the question is only worth 2 marks which makes me think it should be fairly simple.. I just wasn't 100% sure my answer was valid

Comment: I think the intention is to use a series to calculate $\pi$, your example is not particularly useful for this purpose!

Comment: Perhaps you were expected to write $3, .1, .04, .001,\ldots$.

Comment: Your answer is just fine. Are you sure it is a finite sum, or were you asked for $\sum_0^\infty$? If so, your answer would still be fine. If we want the terms to be *rational*, then we will need something fancier, like the fact that $\frac{\pi}{4}=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots$.

Comment: Either you made a typo in writing this down, or the instructor did. Your sum is indexed by $i$, but your summand has $n$ in its subscript, which your sum indicates is the final index. Also, what exactly does $(x_n)_n$ mean? Is that supposed to be something like $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?

Answer (score 1):

For $i \geq 1$ let $\pi_i$ be the $i$th digit of $\pi$ after the decimal place, and $\pi_0 = 3$. Then $\sum_0^\infty \pi_i 10^{-i} = \pi$.

Comment: Not quite, but I see what you mean. You will have to divide by increasing powers of 10 to shift the digit into place. But I get the spirit of what you intend.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, silly mistake.

Comment: I'm sorry to be pedantic, but let's nail it down. In the end, it's a clever idea, yet simple--never occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

$$x_n=-\frac4{2n+1}\cdot\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n)!!}\qquad;\qquad x_n=(-1)^n\frac4{2n+1}$$